# find values in div, compare and color parent container

Tags: jquery

I need to compare the value of .val1 against the value .val2. If val1 is greater than val1 the container #benchmark gets the background-color red else the color green. 
Like to see this done with jquery.

```
    <div id="benchmark">
score team 1<div id="val1">8</div>
score team 2<div id="val2">10</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please be more careful. In div you have "=", but no attribute before. What solution you tried before you post that here? It´s simply, have you tried to look into jQuery docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct html is

```
    <div id="benchmark">
score team 1<div id="val1">8</div>
score team 2<div id="val2">10</div>
   </div>
```

To find value , use

```
$("#val1").text();
```

//So code is :

```
var value1=parseInt($("#val1").text());
var value2=parseInt($("#val2").text());


if(value1>value2)
{
    $("#benchmark").css('background-color', 'red');
}  
else 
{ 
    $("#benchmark").css('background-color', 'green');
}
```

***[`Demo Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/DKKC8/4/)***